# Bash variables appear in TeamCity build status without substitution

Tags: teamcity

TeamCity has a neat feature of [reporting build status from build steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2018.1/build-script-interaction-with-teamcity.html#progressreporting), which gets displayed in the web UI. I'm using it at the end of a Bash script (Runner type: SSH Exec) to signify successful deployment like so:

```bash
echo "##teamcity[buildStatus text='{build.status.text}. Deployed to ${TARGET_HOST}.']"
```

However, when the deployment fails early, I still see a weird appearance of this message in the build status without Bash substitution even though the `echo` command was never executed:

```
SSH exit-code 1 (new). Deployed to ${TARGET_HOST}.
```

While monitoring the successful builds more closely, I've noticed that the incorrect status appears for a short while just before the end of the build:

```
Step 3/3 (deployment). Deployed to ${TARGET_HOST}.
```

But the glitch disappears when the build finishes:

```
Success. Deployed to host.example.com.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hello! What version of TeamCity do you use?

Comment: TeamCity Enterprise 2022.04.2 (build 108655)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Short answer

Use the following Bash snippet instead:

```bash
TEAMCITY_GLITCH_WORKAROUND='teamcity[buildStatus'
echo "##${TEAMCITY_GLITCH_WORKAROUND} text='{build.status.text}. Deployed to ${TARGET_HOST}.']"
```

#### Long answer

This is a quirk of how SSH Exec runner executes the Bash script. As per [TeamCity documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/2018.1/build-script-interaction-with-teamcity.html) (emphasis mine):

> **Service Messages**
>
> Service messages are specially constructed **pieces of text** that are used to pass commands/information about the build from the build script to the TeamCity server.
>
> To be processed by TeamCity, they need to be written to the **standard output stream** of the build, i.e. printed or echoed from a build step.

It means that for TeamCity to update the build status text, a string of form `##teamcity[buildStatus text='your text here']` needs to appear in the standard output stream. If you look at the `echo` command, you'll see that it contains the same kind of string! After all, you're trying to print it. The part underlined in the following snippet corresponds to `your text here`:

```bash
#                interpreted by TeamCity before Bash executes the command
#                                         |
#     /-----------------------------------+----------------------------------------\
echo "##teamcity[buildStatus text='{build.status.text}. Deployed to ${TARGET_HOST}.']"
#                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you look at the start of the build log for the SSH Exec build step, you'll see that it starts with `Executing commands:` and then a listing of the whole script. Build step runner SSH Exec prints the script into standard output, so TeamCity "sees" them (this glitch can be observed even when the log message is part of a comment). If Bash executes them (as in the successful deploy example from the question), then the build message gets updated by whatever Bash has calculated with substitution.

Extracting a part of the string into a separate variable avoids TeamCity seeing the pattern it is looking for the first time. It will only see the fully formed string in the standard output stream after Bash prints it.